# What roxygen should I put when I use a function of another package in my function

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am writing many functions and I am trying to document using [roxygen2](http://roxygen.org/roxygen2-manual.pdf)

I use the [futile.logger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futile.logger/index.html) package a lot, say I use the `flog.debug` function in a function. What `@*` should I use to document it ?

Comment: I don't understand. If you import a function, you don't document it, but rely on the documentation in its original package.

Comment: Yes, use `@import` and also declare Imports in the Description

Comment: Can I get an answer guys ? Looks like there are different opinions ?

Comment: There are not two different opinions. You can let `roxygen2` write your Imports file (but you don't have to). But that is not related to documentation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, being aware of your

```
sessionInfo() 
getwd() # your R's working directory
.libPaths() # your R's library location
```

**Step0** Download and install the necessary packages:

```
library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)
library(digest)
```

**Step1** Put all your related ".R" files (yourfunction1.R, yourfunction2.R, yourfunction3.R) to your R's working directory.

**Step2** Create your package skeleton in your R's working directory: 
Be sure that there is no folder named "yourpackage" in your R's working directory before running the following command. (from R's console)

```
package.skeleton(name = "yourpackage", code_files = c("yourfunction1.R", "yourfunction2.R", "yourfunction3.R"), path = ".")
```

After running `package.skeleton`, the folder yourpackage is created in your R's Working Directory.

Delete `Read-and-delete-me` file from Windows Explorer.
Delete "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder
(Do NOT delete "yourpackage.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder!)

**Step3** At the end of the preamble of your ".R" file (yourfunction.R), put the following (if you had not done it so in Step1):

```
#' @importFrom futile.logger flog.debug
#' @export
yourfunction <- function(...) {...
```

**Step4** In the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package, in the `Imports` part, add:

```
Imports:
    futile.logger(>= VersionNumber)
```

where VersionNumber is the version number of the futile.logger package you are using. You can find the version number by right-click any function (from yourpackage) in Object Browser of RevolutionREnterprise; and going the bottom of the resultant .html help file. There, the version number of the package is shown.

In Step2, package.skeleton automatically produced a NAMESPACE file whose content is:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Do not handle this NAMESPACE file manually.

**Step5** roxygenize the package you wanna create ("yourpackage")

```
library(roxygen2)
roxygenize("yourpackage")
```

Upon roxygenization, the content of the NAMESPACE file of yourpackage is automatically converted from `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` to

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(yourfunction)
importFrom(futile.logger,flog.debug)
```

**Step6** Build your package:
(first, delete "src-i386" and "src-x64" folders (if any) in YourR'sWorkingDirectoryFolder\yourpackage folder from Windows Explorer)
(Be sure again that there is no "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder. If there is, delete it before building)

```
build("yourpackage")
```

**Step7** Install your package:

```
install("yourpackage")
```

**Step8** Check that all is going well by loading your package and running a function in the package.

```
library(yourpackage)
yourfunction(6,1,2) # "yourfunction" is a function in the package "yourpackage"
```

**Step9** Check that your package is loadable to CRAN (Comprehensive R Archieve Network) (if you wanna share your package):

(first, delete "src-i386" and "src-x64" folders (if any) in YourR'sWorkingDirectoryFolder\yourpackage folder from Windows Explorer)
(Be sure again that there is no "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder. If there is, delete it before checking)

From DOS Command Prompt:
Start – cmd  - Enter. Pass to R's working directory (your R's working directory is known via getwd()) and do CRAN check:

```
cd C:\Users\User\Documents\Revolution
R CMD check yourpackage
```

From R's console:

```
devtools::check("C:/Users/User/Documents/Revolution/yourpackage")
```