# Error while importing mice functions in R package

Tags: r, r-package, r-mice

I would like to include the mice::mice function in my package to perform imputation on my data.

I use Roxygen to list imports

```
#' @param data dataset to be used for imputation
#' @importFrom dplyr select_
#' @importFrom mice mice complete
#' @return A list
#' @export
#' 
impute_data <- function(data, vars, seed)
{
     data_used <- select_(data,vars)
     mice_data <- complete(mice(data_used, seed = seed))
     return(mice_data)
}
```

This function works fine when I test the code, however when I build the package and try to use it, I get the following error

```
Error in check.method(setup, data) : 
  The following functions were not found: mice.impute.pmm,mice.impute.pmm, mice.impute.pmm, mice.impute.pmm, mice.impute.pmm
```

I tried to add to the imports all the functions mentioned in the error but it had no effect whatsoever on the outcome.

What am I missing? I've never found such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to handle the DESCRIPTION file! You only handle impute_data.R.

Your question is quite similar to:
[What roxygen should I put when I use a function of another package in my function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111471/what-roxygen-should-i-put-when-i-use-a-function-of-another-package-in-my-functio/37310328#37310328)

I gave answer there (Please search for similar questions before posting any question). For your case:

First, being aware of your

```
sessionInfo() 
getwd() # your R's working directory
.libPaths() # your R's library location
```

**Step0** Download and install the necessary packages:

```
library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)
library(digest)
```

**Step1** Put all your related ".R" files (yourfunction1.R, yourfunction2.R, yourfunction3.R, impute_data.R) to your R's working directory.

**Step2** Create your package skeleton in your R's working directory: 
Be sure that there is no folder named "yourpackage" in your R's working directory before running the following command. (from R's console)

```
package.skeleton(name = "yourpackage", code_files = c("yourfunction1.R", "yourfunction2.R", "yourfunction3.R", "impute_data.R"), path = ".")
```

After running `package.skeleton`, the folder yourpackage is created in your R's Working Directory.

Delete `Read-and-delete-me` file from Windows Explorer.
Delete "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder
(Do NOT delete "yourpackage.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder!)

**Step3** At the end of the preamble of your ".R" file (impute_data.R), put the following (if you had not done it so in Step1):

```
#' @importFrom mice mice
#' @importFrom mice complete
#' @export
impute_data <- function(...) {...
```

**Step4** In the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package, in the `Imports` part, add:

```
Imports:
    mice(>= VersionNumber)
```

where VersionNumber is the version number of the mice package you are using. You can find the version number by right-click any function (from yourpackage) in Object Browser of RevolutionREnterprise; and going the bottom of the resultant .html help file. There, the version number of the package is shown.

In Step2, package.skeleton automatically produced a NAMESPACE file whose content is:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Do not handle this NAMESPACE file manually.

**Step5** roxygenize the package you wanna create ("yourpackage")

```
library(roxygen2)
roxygenize("yourpackage")
```

Upon roxygenization, the content of the NAMESPACE file of yourpackage is automatically converted from `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` to

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(impute_data)
importFrom(mice,mice)
importFrom(mice,complete)
```

**Step6** Build your package:
(first, delete "src-i386" and "src-x64" folders (if any) in YourR'sWorkingDirectoryFolder\yourpackage folder from Windows Explorer)
(Be sure again that there is no "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder. If there is, delete it before building)

```
build("yourpackage")
```

**Step7** Install your package:

```
install("yourpackage")
```

**Step8** Check that all is going well by loading your package and running a function in the package.

```
library(yourpackage)
impute_data(a,b,1235) # "impute_data" is the function in the package "yourpackage"
```

**Step9** Check that your package is loadable to CRAN (Comprehensive R Archieve Network) (if you wanna share your package):

(first, delete "src-i386" and "src-x64" folders (if any) in YourR'sWorkingDirectoryFolder\yourpackage folder from Windows Explorer)
(Be sure again that there is no "yourpackage-package.Rd" file in YourR'sWorkingDirectory\yourpackage\man folder. If there is, delete it before checking)

From DOS Command Prompt:
Start – cmd  - Enter. Pass to R's working directory (your R's working directory is known via getwd()) and do CRAN check:

```
cd C:\Users\User\Documents\Revolution
R CMD check yourpackage
```

From R's console:

```
devtools::check("C:/Users/User/Documents/Revolution/yourpackage")
```

Comment: Hi, I am using RStudio and all this stuff is either handled by default or already taken care (by me), I'm sorry I forgot to add this in the question. This does not work at all. But I found the solution, apparently, mice package requires you to set '@importMethodsFrom mice' in the documentation. This will get it to work.

Comment: Little correction, apparently the solution I found did not work... I found a better solution by referencing each time the namespace mice.. Ex: mice::complete, mice::mice. Not elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and even if the post is older,

recently, I came across the same problem and the proposed solutions by 
Erdogan CEVHER and mickkk did not work for me. I solved it by actively loading the mice package, while loading my own package. For more detailed information consult [R-Package-Dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies).

In addition to the steps required during package development, here is what I recommend:

**Part 1:** Add mice to the `Depends:` (**not** `Import:`) field in the DESCRIPTION file of your package.

```
Depends: mice (>= VERSIONNUMBER)
```

**Part 2:** Use `import(mice)` in NAMESPACE (only for `devtools::check()`)

```
import(mice)
```

**Part 3:** Reference each function using `mice::`, for example

```
mice::mice(data, method="pmm")
```